# Word for "Someone who seeks investment for a company"

Tags: single-word-requests, finance

What is a word for someone who tries to get investment for a company? This may be someone who works for the company or who doesn't work for the company...

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please [edit] this to show us how you would like to use the word in a sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **money/fund/investor finder** is one who merely introduces a potential investor to a company seeking capital.

A (licensed) "*broker*" recommends the purchase of financial assets, negotiating terms of the offering, attending meetings where the merits of the investment are discussed, valuing the securities, and handling funds.

Comment: Yes I'd say Broker makes the most sense.

Answer (score 1):

***[Promoter](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/p/promoter.asp)*** is the term generally used:

> - *An individual or company that, for a fee, helps raise money for some type of investment activity.* Most often, promoters raise money for a company through offering investment vehicles other than traditional stocks and bonds, such as limited partnerships and direct investment activities. Often times, these promoters are paid in company stock or free entrance into the investment activity as compensation for their work in raising funds from others.

(Investopidia)

Answer (score 0):

A  ***financier*** may be one possibility.

Comment: Financier:  one that engages in investing or raising large amounts of money.. 
http://www.thefreedictionary.com/financier